# Permission Errror

Tags: python, scripting, export, error

when I try to export my objects via a python script:

```
    import bpy
import os

blend_file_path = bpy.data.filepath
directory = 'Y:/P/Programme/'

#DAE
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath=directory, filter_blender=False, filter_image=False, filter_movie=False, filter_python=False, filter_font=False, filter_sound=False, filter_text=False, filter_btx=False, filter_collada=True, filter_folder=True, filemode=8)

#ABC
bpy.ops.wm.alembic_export(filepath=directory, selected=False, renderable_only=False,visible_layers_only=False, flatten=False, uvs=False, packuv=True,  normals=True, vcolors=True, face_sets=True, subdiv_schema=False, apply_subdiv=False, global_scale=1, triangulate=False, quad_method='SHORTEST_DIAGONAL', ngon_method='BEAUTY')   



#3DS
bpy.ops.export_scene.autodesk_3ds(filepath = directory, axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z', filter_glob="*.3ds") 

#FBX
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath = directory, check_existing=True, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', bake_anim=False, object_types={'EMPTY', 'MESH', 'OTHER'}, mesh_smooth_type = 'FACE')

#OBJ
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=directory, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl", use_animation=False, use_mesh_modifiers=True, use_smooth_groups=True, use_normals=True, use_materials=True)

#X3D
bpy.ops.export_scene.x3d(filepath=directory, check_existing=True, axis_forward='Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.x3d", use_mesh_modifiers=True, use_triangulate=False, use_normals=True, global_scale=1.0)
```

it works with the collada and ABC export flawlessly but all the other exports give me an permissionError:

```
    Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\P\Programme\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.79\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    return export_obj.save(context, **keywords)
  File "Y:\P\Programme\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.79\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\export_obj.py", line 853, in save
    EXPORT_PATH_MODE=path_mode,
  File "Y:\P\Programme\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.79\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\export_obj.py", line 795, in _write
    progress,
  File "Y:\P\Programme\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.79\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\export_obj.py", line 330, in write_file
    with open(filepath, "w", encoding="utf8", newline="\n") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Y:\P\Programme\'

location: Y:\P\Programme\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.79\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189
```

and yes I already checked the Permission settings for this folder and I did try it out with other folders, too. But none worked.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4):

From the code you supplied, it looks like you are trying to export the file as "Y:/P/Programme/", which is a folder and not a file.

For the exporters to work, `filepath` expect a full filepath in the format of `path\to\folder\filename.ext`